# std::vector gives different results in Linux and Windows

Tags: c++, optimization, mingw, stdvector

I have a task to analyze how a `vector` behaves when a `Node` (an object consisting of a `long` value) is prepended to it.
I have placed a counter in the copy constructor of a `Node` to see how many times it is being called when the vector is moved to a new location i.e when `vector` grows.

I get the following results:

Windows - MinGW compiler:

```
|--------------------Vector-------------------|  
 Size      Time  Creates   Copies     Destroys
 100      0 ms      100      411          411
```

Linux:

```
|--------------------Vector-------------------|  
 Size      Time  Creates   Copies     Destroys
 100      0 ms      100      227          227
```

Node.cpp

```
Node::Node(const Node& x){
    this->value = x.get_value();
    copy_count++;
}
```

SortedVector.cpp

```
vector<Node> data;

void SortedVector::prepend(const long value){
    const Node x(value);
    data.insert(data.begin(), x);
}
```

A matter of relief is that the copy constructor count is same as in the destructor, but can you please help me understand the difference in the outputs in Linux and Windows?

Comment: different implementations. Most likely they grow the vector by different amounts when it needs to resize.

Comment: Your question could benefit from a [mcve], rather than two snippets of code

Comment: You are comparing an implementation on two different OSs. A number of issues can effect the speed such as what background tasks are going on during your test, interrupts, context switching of other processes etc.

Comment: We'd also need to know exact versions of each compiler, compiler command lines, etc. Basically, if you're not providing enough info for a [MCVE], it's pretty hard to help.

Comment: There were lot many files involved in the problem, I tired to be very specific.Sorry about that. 
Anyhow here is the link https://github.com/maddy302/Vector-Vs-List.git
Compiler version - C++14

Comment: The subset of code required to demonstrate the results you are asking about only requires one file with a length of probably around 50 lines.

Comment: C++14 still leaves plenty of room for differing implementations. What Shadow Ranger is looking for is relatively easy to get with `g++ -v` Note that there are a few dozen different flavours of MinGW out there these days, but the GCC version should be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is due to them being different implementations.

You didn't show your code and so I can't research the differences in implementations of the methods you used but I believe the main difference is in the implementation of `std::vector`. It all depends on how the inserts are made in the vector, especially because you're storing the **values** of Nodes instead of pointers. This means that there's no objection whatsoever to an object inside the vector being copied whenever necessary.

A possible guess of a difference between the implementation of `insert` could be that one of the implementations uses realloc to increase the array's size whenever the capacity needs to be increased while the other uses malloc and then copies all the values to the new array. If the realloc'ed memory, in the first case, was just the same memory address with increased size, no copies would be needed.

P.S.: For future reference, please read [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before you ask a question like this one. It's important to remember that when we ask for help, other people aren't as aware of the code as the one who wrote it.

**Update**

To check if the difference is in the way the vector's capacity is increased, you could call [`std::vector::reserve`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/) before starting to insert into the vectors. Call it with `100` or more in the argument so the vector has the capacity for the number `Node`s you are going to insert.

Comment: IMO, it'd be far more beneficial to not answer OP's question than it is to answer it and link them to [ask]. If everyone's question got answered regardless of whether they followed the guidelines on asking, then nobody would do it anyway. Because of the lack of detail, your answer is mostly guesswork, but it's not a bad answer

Comment: @Tas You make an interesting point. I answered the question because I understood it besides its bad formulation. Also, I know my answer wasn't perfect because he didn't follow the guidelines, rendering me clueless as to what the code was but I tried to help nonetheless. I have a soft spot for optimization problems. Sorry

Comment: Gcc libstdc++, doee not use realloc.

Comment: `vector` growth, for objects which are not trivially copyable and d'tible, cannot be implemented in terms of `realloc` because of its immediate fallback to the equivalent of `malloc` + `memcpy`. Also, `realloc` does not make space at the front of the allocation (it may prepend space but will then e.g. `memmove` the previous contents to the front). An implementation could, of course, reuse some non-standard functions that are also used to provide `realloc`.

Answer (score 1):

You may find the table on this page useful [useful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array). It lists the geometrical ratio used to expand vector sizes on various compilers.

The facts your results differ should be expected. There are many solutions to the problems of [memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management)/[memory fragmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragmentation_(computing)). Each has it's own strengths and weaknesses. My advice would be to trust the compiler writer to tune the vector to get the best out of the default allocation scheme, but if you need more control, manually manage the allocations with [reserve](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/) and [shrink to fit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/shrink_to_fit/).

It is almost never a good idea to have [side-effecting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) copy operations, but what your question highlights is that this is a requirement of vectors.